# Not able to access web api calls in a api/controller format

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

Hi I am developing one application using web api2 and accessing calls via angularjs. I created web api calls and hosted in iis server(public ip). I am accessing the web api2 methods in the below format.

```
 $http.post('http://111.93.133.98:4500/api/NCT_Login/', credentials).success(function (response) { alert(response); });
```

This is my web api config.cs file.

```
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}"
```

This is my controller code.

```
  public class NCT_LoginController : ApiController
{
    public NCTEntities entityObject = new NCTEntities();
    [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE")]

    public IHttpActionResult Post(LoginClass obj)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                obj.User_Password = PasswordEncryption.sha256_hash(obj.User_Password);
                bool result = (from c in entityObject.NCT_UserRegistration where obj.User_Name ==c.User_Name && obj.User_Password == c.User_Password select c).Any();
                if(result==true)
                {

                    obj.UserRole = (from c in entityObject.NCT_UserRegistration where obj.User_Name == c.User_Name && obj.User_Password == c.User_Password select c.User_Role).FirstOrDefault();
                    obj.Success = 0;
                    obj.User_Password = "";
                    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, obj);
                    var newSessionId = new SessionIDManager().CreateSessionID(HttpContext.Current);
                    var cookie = new CookieHeaderValue("session-id", newSessionId);
                    cookie.Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(1);
                    cookie.Domain = Request.RequestUri.Host;
                    cookie.Path = "/";
                    response.Headers.AddCookies(new[] { cookie });
                    return ResponseMessage(response);
                }
                else
                {
                    return Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, 1);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                return Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, 1);
            }
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
        {
            foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
                    eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
                foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                        ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
            throw;
        }
    }
```

If i remove api from route template I am able to access api's and if i put api.NCT_Login then I am getting preflight error. I am not sure what i am missing here. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please share the complete controller class

Comment: We need the controller class name as well :)

Comment: Sorry. Api name is NCT_LoginController. Mvc5 controller name is Homecontroller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would decorate the post method with a attribute route like this

```
[RoutePrefix("api/NCT_Login")]
public class NCT_LoginController : ApiController
{
    public NCTEntities entityObject = new NCTEntities();
    [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE")]

    [Route("Login")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Post(LoginClass obj)
    {
```

This would set the route to `api/NCT_Login/Login`

IMO its a good practice to use [attribute routing](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) as it gets very clear what each method route is. 
Also when controllers grow its easy to define new routes on the same http verb

Comment: Make sure he has enable attribute routing in the api config and you can keep `[Route()]` for the Login action so that the could POST it to `api/NCT_Login/` itself:)

Comment: @Developer isn't attribute routing enable by default in web api 2?

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole Yes, That would be the correct route:)

Comment: Working fine. Thank you.